# Appcelerator update broke module panel

Tags: appcelerator

I updated Appcelerator, and now when I relaunch, all of my modules that are listed have the yellow 'warning' icon, hovering over them says they aren't supported by the SDK, and clicking the 'Add' icon loads a blank list.

I also rolled back and its still broke.  Anyone else have this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can rebuild your module with the latest Ti SDK then try to use. Also, if you use third party module then check their update version which is compatible with the latest version of Ti SDK.

- http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Extending_Titanium_Mobile

Hope this helps.